# How to match two patterns using OR?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I need to use `grep` and `awk` in order to match two types of patterns but I cannot figure out the syntax.

My file has values such as:

```
sample1,gicode1,123,4541,221,3661,Sodalis sp.1
sample2,gicode1,123,0322,12,112342,Sodalis sp.2
sample3,gicode1,112,4541,00,2342,Candidatus sp.
sample4,gicode1,2341,4541,00,9606,Homo sapiens
```

I need to grab the count of lines that have `Sodalis`. This can be in the name (so 7th column) or based on taxid since sometimes the naming that comes up is not accurate. The ID is the 6th column.

My issue is that sometimes the IDs in the 6th column can match to values in other columsn which are *not* ids. If I want the `Sodalis` species with the ID `2342`, it shows up properly in sample 3, but it is also the scoring value in sample 4 (3rd column).

I can grab the ID in the proper column using `awk -F, '$6==2342'` or simply the name using `grep 'Sodalis'` but I am having an issue combining both as in the following:

```
cat myfile.txt | grep "Sodalis" OR awk -F, '$6==2342' | wc -l
```

The return should be 3, but I get either 2 (for `grep`) or just 1 (for `awk`). I've tried many variations of this with `||` or `&` even:

```
cat myfile.txt | grep "Sodalis" || cat myfile.txt | awk -F, '$6==2342'
```

But it gives the answer 1.

I know with grep I can also use `grep -E 'Sodalis|2342'` but this unfortunately returns 4 because the second pattern is matching to sample 4 where it the scoring value happens to be `2342`. Is there a way to `grep` a value based on a certain column? I need the full line to also appear because I want to save those results as a separate file called `Sodalis.txt`.

Comment: Regarding `I need to use grep and awk` - no, you never need grep when you're using awk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need for grep here - awk is perfectly capable of matching patterns:

```
awk -F, '/Sodalis/ || $6==2342' myfile.txt | wc -l
```

or

```
awk -F, '/Sodalis/ || $6==2342 {c++} END{print c}' myfile.txt
```

(responding to comments) if you want to restrict the match of `Sodalis` to the 7th column only, and perhaps read a list of 6th column IDs one per line from a file `ids.txt`:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{ids[$1]; next} $7 ~ /Sodalis/ || $6 in ids' ids.txt myfile.txt
```

Comment: Oh I knewww I had to use ```||``` but I kept using it out of the quotes! Thanks so much!

Comment: Or even `$7 ~ /Sodalis/` if there's ever need to restrict that condition to a particular column/field too.

Comment: Is there also a way in awk to make it match a long list of strings? Some cases I have 10 IDs and I think it would be tedious to write ```$6 ==2342 || $6==310 || etc``` for each ID I want to match

Comment: @KBwonder, regex match with alternation in the pattern: `$6 ~ /^(2342|310|1234)$/`

Comment: @KBwonder if you have more than a few, get them into an array (are the IDs in a file somewhere?), then you can use `$6 in arr`

Comment: @rowboat Oh yea they can be in a separate file as a list, would that be the array file?

Comment: @KBwonder [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged. Please just ask a new followup question if you have one.